# PHP MYSQL Statement Execute Won't Retrieve Data For Particular Variable in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

```
//Positional Params
$emailToken = $_GET['token'];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM signup WHERE token = ?';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$emailToken]);
$message = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Basically I have a email token i parse from the url and want to check whether in the database does it exist or not. No matter what it won't valid even though i checked and echo the emailToken is the exact same.

I tested with another variable

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM signup WHERE email = ?';
$stmt->execute(['asd@gmail.com']);
```

And it works. Any idea?

Comment: Does your code actually have the `(` in `$_GET(['token']`?

Comment: $emailToken = $_GET['token'];
Yes on top

Comment: Did you try removing [] in $stmt->execute([$emailToken]);?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and correct the code.

Comment: @SajithaRathnayake do not advise things if you're not sure they help.

Comment: @SajithaRathnayake Yes i did tried that. It works if i put $email = "asd@gmail.com"
and asd@gmail.com is in the mySQL database. but token generated even though its exist and successfully parse through the URL , won't find it in the SQL database.

Comment: `$emailToken = $_GET(['token'];` should be `$emailToken = $_GET['token'];`

Comment: @NigelRen Sorry removed the parentheses as well.

Comment: @DennisOng Try this
$stmt->execute(array('token' ,$emailToken)); You can refer pdo thing here https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepare.php

Comment: @SajithaRathnayake Tried it, it kinda dumps every rows of data from the table.

Comment: @u_mulder Its not a big deal. I'm not going to destroy the world :)

Answer (score 1):

It might just be personal preference, but I like being more specific with the bind variables and the syntax never seems to fail me.

```
$emailToken = $_GET['token'];
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM signup WHERE token = :token';
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':token', $emailToken, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stmt->execute();
$message = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

building a string with the syntax (never keep code like this, it is only a test)

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM signup WHERE token = '" . $_GET['token'] . "'";
var_dump( $sql );
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$message = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

then you can test this outputted code in a query tool to make sure it is syntactically correct.

Comment: I added your code to mine seems to have an error..?

 $emailToken = ($_GET['token']);
 //Initialize PDO
 $dsn = 'mysql:host='.$host .';dbname=' .$dbName;
 $pdo = new PDO($dsn,$user,$password);
 
 $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE,PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
 
 //Positional Params
 $sql = 'SELECT * FROM signup WHERE token = ?';
 $stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
 $stmt->execute([$emailToken]);
 $message = $stmt->fetchAll();

Is my code

Comment: Personal preference is not going to fix the issue and you copied a syntax error right into your code.

Comment: I didnt copy anything, I typed it into the comment box, but you are correct, there is a syntax error, I was just trying to illustrate a different and more specific way of coding

Comment: @Piyper Hi I tried your code once again after fixing the syntax, still the same result. can't retrieve the token from SQL :(

Comment: I know it WILL open you up to code injection, but JUST AS A TEST, change this to string concats instead of bind variables ,then you can output the actual SQL prior to executing it. $sql =  "select  * from signup where token = '$emailToken'"; var_dump( $sql); , this way you can see if the sql syntax is correct

Comment: @Piyper Sorry, i don't fully get your latest comment.

Comment: what I am suggesting is you construct a SQL string with the value concatenated into the string rather than using bind variables, you would be able to output the exact syntax that would be executed. once you do that, you could then copy that syntax into phpmyadmin or some other tool and try executing it to see if there is some sort of syntax error. But it would start with you building the string in the first place. and as stated before, this would be for testing only, you don't want to leave that code there because it opens you up to SQL injection.

Comment: For example. maybe you spelled the table name wrong or something like that, outputting the syntax provides clarity